# How to parse list of objects in react-i18next?

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I'm having a JSON-file with the following structure:

```
{
  "topPart": {
    "title": "Hello",
    "list": [
      "Test1",
      "Test2",
      "Test3",
      "Test4"
    ]
  }
}
```

I can call `title` in my app by doing following:

```
const [t] = useTranslation("main");

//some code

<h1>{t('topPart.title')}</h1>
```

However, if I am trying to get a list of translations, the following structure doesn't work:

```
const [t] = useTranslation("main");

//some code
<ul>
{t('topPart.list').map((item, index) => {
                            return(
                                <li key={index}>{item}</li>
                            )
                        })}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer is simple:

use `{returnObject: true}`

```
t('topPart.list', {returnObjects: true});
```